# Should I add go dep vendor/ to .gitignore?

Tags: go

Should I add `go dep` `vendor/` folder to `.gitignore`?
Now I have `vendor/` in `.gitignore`, so every deploy will call `dep ensure`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`github/gitignore/Go.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Go.gitignore) doesn't add `vendor/` to its `.gitignore` file.

This causes its content should be versioned, recorded in the Git repository, instead of being potentially generated, and may respond to the following needs:

- avoiding reference changes
- disappearing projects
- vendoring tool may evolve (**[dep](https://github.com/golang/dep)** to **[vgo](https://github.com/golang/vgo)** to **[modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)**), ...
- if you made modifications to vendor dependencies in your Git repository, you should probably track those

On the other hand, [`gitignore.io/api/go`](https://www.gitignore.io/api/go) **does** add `vendor/` to its `.gitignore`.

So in conclusion, you might as well ignore it if you're not in any of the situations stated above.

---

> I'm in a sort of predicament: my colleague has issues with his go installation which requires  vendoring his dependencies. Mine works fine. I don't want to add unnecessary stuff to the repository

That highlights a common dilemma in software development: making sure that all team members can work in a stable and consistent environment without cluttering the repository with dependencies that can be managed by tools.

In your case, you could consider:

- Docker or virtualization, virtual environments to standardize development environments across your team. That way, dependencies and tooling are encapsulated in a container or virtual machine, minimizing the need to modify the host environment (e.g., the specific Go installation).
- If vendoring is necessary for development but you prefer not to clutter the repository, you could adopt a hybrid approach. Keep the `vendor/` directory out of version control but provide scripts or documentation for generating it when needed. That way, developers can generate the `vendor/` directory locally.
- If modifications to dependencies are common, consider maintaining a private repository for your vendored dependencies. That repository can be referenced by your project, making sure that all developers use the same version of dependencies without directly including them in the main project repository.
- [Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) are now (2024) the current standard for dependency management in Go. Modules allow for precise dependency versioning and can potentially obviate the need for vendoring in many cases. Make sure all team members use a compatible version of Go that supports modules.

Comment: I'm in a sort of predicament: my colleague has issues with his go installation which requires  vendoring his dependencies. Mine works fine. I don't want to add unnecessary stuff to the repository 